# SharePoint list access through PowerShell in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, powershell

I am getting an error:

> Cannot index into a null array at line with "$Web.Lists"

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -site "https://dTH.ca/sites/universal"

$list = $web.Lists["Folder Files"]
```

The same script works well in staging environment but fails in production.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Do u have checked $web to confirm that is Null or Not?
I highly recommend that install PnP PowerShell in server(or any other OS) and use that for work with list and lib instead of sharepoint PowerShell.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Yes I get a value for $web and Null value for $web.lists. Is it because of space between the document library name.  I have also tried $list = $web.Lists["Folder%20Files"]

Comment: you can use pnp powershell for it more easy. in there you can pass list display name or List GUID for find a list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "https://dTH.ca/sites/universal"`

Change `site` to `identity`. I assume you are handling a site collection having a bunch of sub sites. Using `site` will return all subsites, `$web` will be collection of sub-sites which does not have a the **lists** property